# Matching algorithm with liking function

Tags: algorithm

I have an algorithmic problem.
I want to match two equally sized groups of people. There's a liking function which  assigns every pair (consisting of one person of group A and one person of group B) a liking score.
I now want to match every person of group A with exactly one person of group B and I want the sum of the scores of all matches to be maximal.
I designed a naive algorithm which tries out all possibilities and then chooses the best one, but it's runtime is n! (where n is the amount of people in each group).
Is there a faster algorithm? Or at least a fast approximation algorithm?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide us with an example input and output ?

Comment: This isn't posed exactly as [the stable Marriage problem,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_marriage_problem) but it may be informative to study. Actually, it looks like [the assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) is a better fit.

Comment: This is, indeed, another version of the assignment problem.  You should have found this with your research with the keyword "matching".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that each person is only to be matched once (both directions), this sound like a simple [assignment problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem) (or: minimum weight perfect matching in bipartite graph) which can be solved in polynomial-time (and quite efficient in practice). There is also a lot of software available in many programming-languages.

Opposed to the classic `worker <-> job` view, your view would be: `group A <-> group B`.

As most libraries are somewhat assuming:

- non-negative costs
- minimization

you would need to translate your maximization-problem:

```
x = max(original_likings)
transformed_liking_i_j = x - original_liking_i_j
... solve minimization problem (with transformed likings)
```

This is often called *opportunity loss*.